# Why is 'indexOf' not returning anything?

Tags: javascript, methods, indexof

The [book I am reading](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html) tells me to open up the JavaScript console and try the code `"foo: bar".indexOf(":")`.  I've tried it in many ways.  I tried removing quotation marks, putting it inside a `show()` and `alert()` function.  I just can't seem to tease anything out.

Has something changed in JavaScript?  Has the author made a mistake?  Am I supposed to get no return?  Do I need to append document.write, perhaps?  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MKEc2/ - works fine. Alerts 3 since the index is 0 based.

Comment: At least in the FireBug console, it displays (correctly) `3`

Comment: As all the answers and comments suggest, what you're doing should return a value.  I suspect you're not telling the whole story here, and I've voted to close as "too localized" as this question is unlikely to help any future visitors to the site.

Comment: I agree.  It works in Chrome's `CTRL-Shift-J`.  It's just the console that comes with the book that's fail.

Comment: I don't know, Andy.  This book's pretty popular.  You can vote to close if you want, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes something changed in Firefox 5+
However the console (ctrl-shift-k) still works

[image: Fx konsole]

In the error console (ctrl-shift-J) you will need to wrap it in alert:

[image]

Comment: I think this answer is best because if anyone looks to it in the future, it tells them how to open a JavaScript interpreter inside a popular browser.  I also liked skk's because it uses an alternative to `alert()`, though.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

foo:bar is a property definition in json, and indexOf is supposed to deal with a left value (string variable, constant, or at least something that can have characters in it. I don't know why the book you are reading wants you to do this, but it doesn't seem to be correct. The correct way to use indexOf would be :

```
var myObject = {
   foo:"bar"
}

alert(myObject.foo.indexOf("a"));
```

Comment: Wait... are you saying `"foo:bar".indexOf(":")` is an *incorrect* use of `indexOf()`?

Comment: "foo:bar".indexOf(":") is supposed to work on each browser (IE 7 and older.. I've never tested lol). "foo":bar.indexOf(":") will not, and probably any other way to place quotes will neither. When you talk about a "console", why do you need to write your code there ?

Comment: Fred, I was just using console because it was handy.  The book's asking me to do this to see what it returns so that I can complete an exercise.  I had completed it without using `indexOf()`, but they relied on it heavily, later, so I wanted to see it alone.

Answer (score 1):

try like follows, it should work. Generally the indexOf() will return -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

```
var str="foo:bar";
document.write(str.indexOf(":") + "<br />");
```

The output should be 3

Comment: Doesn't work on the book.  It refreshes my page and says '3' in Chrome, though.  Thank you.